# iPhone session - timeout on inactivity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

When the user successfully log into my app, session starts, after X period of inactivity the session will time out.

Now how do you detect, the user to see if his active using the application or not using it?

1) Check every on button?

2) check on screen load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most elegant way I've found to do this is to use a category on `UIApplication` that provides a `sendEvent:` method that resets an `NSTimer` (after calling its superclass implementation of course).  If the timer goes off, post a notification.  Listen for the notification everywhere you want to react to the timeout.  Doing it this way means that you don't have to add code all through your app to reset the timer on every interaction.

Having said that, I agree with Shaggy Frog, this isn't typical behaviour for an iOS application, so it's not usually a good idea from a HCI perspective.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking "How do I define activity", you could always reset a timer after a touch event is received, whose callback triggers the "user is inactive event".

I can't speak much for your overall design choice here, as I don't think most iOS users expect their apps to behave in this manner. Think of your users and proceed with caution.

Comment: If you use a time NSTimer for example, will you have to check the touch event received on every screen? can also call the timer to reset when the screen changes, but again still would have to do this on every screen - is there a better way?

Comment: @001 You probably would have to check every single touch event on every single screen. Is there a better way? Maybe. I think the bigger problem is your fundamental design decision of having a timeout in the first place; the idea that an app can "time out" users due to inactivity is rare, at best on iOS, and is generally something your users will not expect or desire.

Comment: I disagree. We use a single device, which is used by multiple users during our inventory/shipping/receiving process. OUR USERS REQUESTED THIS FEATURE, so that after 5 minutes it would return to the login screen. This way if left on the counter, another user could log in, and use the same device. The assumption here is that everyone has there own iphone/itouch which is NOT necessarily the case in an enterprise environment, where the product is NOT for the consumer :) Just because you can't think of a reason for why you would need it does not mean that it is not required. Take the blinders off,

Comment: Use a time out due to inactivity is suitable for certain applications   like enterprise where sensitive data can be exposed.

Answer (score -1):

You can also check for applicationwillresignactive callback for this.

Comment: This answer is a good suggestion. Assuming you don't want a session timeout shorter than iOS's own inactivity timeout, then just record a time when the app goes to sleep and upon waking, if the elapsed time is too long then logout.