# How to create user session in the xamarin form?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am intend to create a user session in the xamarin form. For example, when a user login to the apps, if the apps is not active for 15 minutes, when he on resume back to the apps, it will auto log out. Do the xamarin forms itself provide this function for me to achieve my goal?

If no, is it i need to provide a variable, and go to the IOS , android project, when the apps on pause , assign the current time value to the variable, when the user on resume back to the project, detect the gap of the current time between the variable, if more than 15 minutes i will quit the apps. Is it correct for you all to create the user session?

Answer (score 2):

We do not have any Session management APIs in Xamarin.Forms, it's same situation on native iOS and Android platforms.

You should code session management on your own for the specific platforms. For example see:

- iOS - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4823280/85606
- Android - http://www.truiton.com/2013/03/android-force-close-application-session-timeout/